# jquery on link click add 1 to variable

Tags: jquery, variables

I'm trying to add 1 to a variable when a next button is clicked which will show a hidden previous button but I can't seem to get the add 1 part to work. I've pasted the code and a link to a jsfiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/huddds/JesBR/1/

HTML

```
  <a href="#" class="prevButton">PREVIOUS</a>
  <a href="#" class="nextButton">NEXT</a>
```

Javascript

```
 nextClicked = 0;
 currentNextClicked = nextClicked;

 $(document).ready(function() {

     $('a.nextButton').live('click', function(){
         nextClicked = currentNextClicked + 1;
         return false;
     });

     if(nextClicked == 0){
         $('a.prevButton').hide();    
     }
     if(nextClicked == 1){
         $('.prevButtonFalse').hide();
         $('.prevButton').show();

     }
     if(nextClicked == 2){

     }
     if(nextClicked == 3){

     }
     if(nextClicked == 4){

     }
 });​
```

CSS

```
 .nextButtonFalse{display:none;}
 .prevButtonFalse{display:none;}
```

Any help would be great, thanks in advance for any responses.

I've decided to go with this option:

HTML

```
 <div>Total : <span id="total">0</span></div>
 <input class="subtract" data-amount="1" type="button" value="PREVIOUS" />
 <input class="add" data-amount="1" type="button" value="NEXT" />
```

jQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.add').click(function() {
      $('#total').text(parseInt($('#total').text()) + parseInt($(this).data('amount')));
   });
 })


 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.subtract').click(function() {
      $('#total').text(parseInt($('#total').text()) - parseInt($(this).data('amount')));
   });
 })
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/huddds/JesBR/20/
​
​
            ​

Comment: your if statements only run when on dom ready... if you need those checks each time you should put them inside your click event handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only checking the value of `nextClicked` on document load. Put it in the on `live` click handler. You also need to update the value of `currentNextClicked`. Maybe moving `currentNextClicked = nextClicked;` into the click handler is what you want?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.nextButton').live('click', function(){
        currentNextClicked = nextClicked;
        nextClicked = currentNextClicked + 1;
        foo();
        return false;
    });

    foo();
});

function foo(){

    if(nextClicked == 0){
        $('a.prevButton').hide();    
    }
    if(nextClicked == 1){
        $('.prevButtonFalse').hide();
        $('.prevButton').show();
    }
    if(nextClicked == 2){

    }
    if(nextClicked == 3){

    }
    if(nextClicked == 4){

    }

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JesBR/19/

Comment: You should include all relevant code in the answer itself, so that it's still useful even if the jsFiddle link expires or the jsFiddle site is down.

Comment: This seems to work for the first case, I've added a second one though and that doesnt seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/huddds/JesBR/15/

Comment: You should also consider what Anthony said, you need to update `currentNextClicked`

Answer (score 0):

You initialise `nextClicked` and `currentNextClicked` both to `0`, then in your `click` event handler you do this:

```
nextClicked = currentNextClicked + 1;
```

That will set `nextClicked` to 1, because 0 + 1 = 1. However, you never change the value of `currentNextClicked`, so the next time you click it's also still going to be setting `nextClicked` to the result of 0 + 1.

Answer (score 0):

As @Anthony said, when you do `nextClicked = currentNextClicked + 1;` you are always getting 1 as the result.

Also, you need to make the following `if` checks after every click and you can hide the `a.prevButton` on load as the `nextClicked` value will initially always be set to `0`.

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/nienn/JesBR/18/

```
nextClicked = 0;

function onClickCheck(){

    if(nextClicked == 0){
        $('a.prevButton').hide();    
    }
    if(nextClicked == 1){
        $('.prevButtonFalse').hide();
        $('.prevButton').show();
    }
    if(nextClicked == 2){

    }
    if(nextClicked == 3){

    }
    if(nextClicked == 4){

    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a.prevButton').hide();
    $('a.nextButton').live('click', function(e){
        nextClicked += 1;        
        onClickCheck ();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});​
```